# If I call a setValue() or similar function of a Qt widget, when is its valueChanged() slot guaranteed to be executed?

Tags: qt, race-condition

Let's say I have multiple input widgets to set up the same parameter. For example, there is a QSlider and a QSpinBox which need to show the same value. In the `valueChanged()` slot of one of them I call the `setValue()` of the other one.
Obviously, this would result in an endless loop of them calling each other.

A similar problem arises when this input widget controls some external resource or device. If the user changes the value, it will send the new value to the external device. But if the external device changes the value (or it is read from a settings file, etc) then I have to update the widget, which in turn will send the value, which in turn will update the widget, and so on.

A third scenario is when I save the values into a file or database, but I have to initialize the widgets to *some* value at the beginning, possibly before I got all the values from the database. But by initializing the widgets at the beginning of my program, they will write that dummy value into the database, overwriting the real values.

The obvious solution for these problems is to just have a bool which allows or forbids the side effects of the `valueChanged()` functions.

For example, if I want to change the value of my slider, I use

```
editing = true;
slider.setValue(value);
editing = false;
```

While I have `if (editing) return;` at the beginning of my `valueChanged()` function.

Assuming I didn't fiddle with setting up the signals and slots manually, but they were done by QtCreator, is there a danger of the slot being called later, for example after the `editing` flag is set to false again? I tried it, and it works, but I am unsure how guaranteed it is.

Answer (score 1):

If you use direct connection (the default for objects in the same thread), the slot is called as soon as the signal is emitted, that is before the setValue method returns.

If you use `Qt::QueuedConnection`, the slot is invoked when control returns to the event loop of the receiver's thread.

See [Qt::ConnectionType](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum)

Comment: Indeed, my observation was that valueChanged is always called before `editing = false;` is executed, I just wanted to be sure I didn't miss some condition under which this might no longer be true.

Comment: If you use direct connection, I can't think any condition under wich this can appen. The signal implementation generated by Qt (with moc) invoke the slot

Answer (score 1):

The way I would go about solving this problem is by having another `QObject` that will be your data model. Your data will be centralized in your model, and will gotten/set via the model. This way your widgets wouldn't need to know about one another and can be created in separate places in your code as long as they can access your model.

Your model will have a method `setValue` and a signal `valueChanged`, so it will look some thing like this:

```
class Model : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    void setValue(const QVariant& value) {
        if (_value != value) {
            _value = value;
            emit valueChanged(_value);
        }
    }

    const QVariant& getValue() const {
        return _value;
    }

public signals:
    void valueChanged(QVariant& value);

private:
    QVariant _value;
}
```

Then your widgets can take the same instance of `Model` as a dependency and listen to its `valueChanged` signal and update themselves. The widgets will also listen to user input, and when the user changes the value then they will change the value in the model. That way the other widgets will get notified about the change.

Your widgets will look like this:

```
class MySlider : public QSlider {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MySlider(QSharedPointer<Model> model, QWidget *parent=nullptr) 
    : QSlider(parent), _model(model) {
        connect(this, &QSlider::valueChanged, this, [this](int value){
            _model->setValue(value);
        });
        connect(_model.data(), &Model::valueChanged, this, &MySlider::onValueChanged);
        //this is to update the widget with the latest value upon creation
        onValueChanged(_model->getValue());

    }

private slots:
    void onValueChanged(const QVariant& value) {
        if (value.toInt() != value()) {
            //this is calling QSlider::setValue
            setValue(value.toInt());
        }
    }
}
```

Before you create all your widgets you can create your model with the default value, so let's assume it's in `main`:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  QApplication a(argc, argv);
  MainWindow w;
  w.show();

  //note that your model doesn't have a parent, it's a shared pointer
  auto model = QSharedPointer<Model>::create();
  auto mySlider1 = new MySlider(model, &w);
  auto mySlider2 = new MySlider(model, &w);

  return a.exec();
}
```

P.S. You can also look into [QDataWidgetMapper](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatawidgetmapper.html) and see if it can accomplish what you're looking for.